# Python bytearray.fromhex fails when string has "16"

Tags: python

In Python 2.7, the function `bytearray.fromhex(string)` gives:

```
ValueError: non-hexadecimal number found in fromhex() arg at position x
```

when the string has '16' in it, like in for example:

```
0200FF001603000E30D03, 0200FF001603004401A03
```

It's like failing if it was decimal and was '84102' just for having '10', the base, in it.

How can I avoid that error?

Comment: No. Both strings are too short (or too long) by one character. Adding any hexadecimal character makes it work. You could have seen that because the error message **does not point at your '16'**.

Comment: Shorter and way longer strings without '16' do not result in error, hence my assumption.

Comment: No. They *do*, irrespective of the presence or absence of '16'. See http://bugs.python.org/issue20279. (That said, I cannot readily find anything mentioning this in the official documentation.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem with 16 existed in the string, the problem is that you try to encode odd length strings - try any valid string with even length and you will see that it is works.